# Running Pentaho Job from Repository With Log

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am running pentaho job from repository using kitchen.bat in windows cmd. I want to save the log file into my C drive, however when I pass the switch (logfile) with the location of the log file. The log file does not generate there.

*Kitchen.bat /rep:DEV-FileRepository /dir:/home/Production/AnalyticsMainProcess /job:AnalyticsMainProcess /param:RunType:NotRerun /level:Basic /logfile:C:\pentaho\logs\log.txt*

And also is it possible to add date stamp in the log file? like log_2020_09_18.txt

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing it properly
For Example: kitchen.bat /file:C:\PRD\runAll.kjb /level:Basic **> C:\LOG\trans.log**

Kindly refer below link
https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/eai/kitchen+user+documentation

Comment: Thanks. This worked however, when an error occurs while running the job it doesnt get logged in the log file, it is being displayed in the cmd windows. Do I have to set up another log for errors only? and also how should I put time stamp on the log file?

Comment: > C:\LOG\trans.log(this is log generation file path) if you have defined this correctly then it should not generate log on CMD, all the logs will be written in this destination file.

No direct way of adding the timestamp in Logfilename.